# PHP Connect/Find Four Game

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently working on a connect four game. Right now I have an array which contains 6 arrays which contain values.
When a person places a chip/counter, I use the x to find the array which contains my values then change my y to my counter id.
Pretty much :

```
$this->fourTables[$gameId]["map"][$xmap][$ymap] = $player->chip;
```

The array I'm using is

```
$map = array(
    0 => array(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), 
    1 => array(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), 
    2 => array(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), 
    3 => array(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), 
    4 => array(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), 
    5 => array(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
);
```

I'm quite bad working with arrays. How would I know if a person got connect 4(straight up, diagonal or straight across)?

Comment: use a ready made solution? https://github.com/10w042/connect-four-php/blob/master/ConnectFour.php

Comment: How would you do that manually? Just pretend you have it on piece of paper and explain every step in detail you would do to check it manually.

Comment: Thanks Unamata, I decided to use that. It also helped me understand what I wanted to do more.